# outline levels without different length of the match

Tags: outline-mode

I'm new to Emacs. I'm trying to use the `outline-mode` with a specific requirement.
I would like to have the number 1 corresponding to the level 1, the number 2 corresponding to level 2 and so on:

```
1keyword_a(first level)
2sub_keyword_aa(second level)
2sub_keyword_ab(second level)
3sub_sub_keyword_aba(third level)

1keyword_b(first level)
2sub_keyword_ba(second level)
3sub_sub_keyword_baa(third level)
```

I understand that outline levels works with the length of the match but I'm wondering whether my requirement is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Drew already gave you the link to [Outline Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Format.html) in his answer. There follows a simple application example. You can copy the stuff into the `*scratch*`-buffer and call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

```el
(defcustom my-outline-regexp "\\([0-9]+\\)"
  "Regular expression to match the beginning of a heading with numbered level."
  :type 'regexp
  :group 'outline)

(defun my-outline-level ()
  "Return the outline level according to `my-outline-regexp'."
  (string-to-number (match-string 1)))

(define-derived-mode my-outline-mode outline-mode "myOutline"
  "Outline mode with numbered levels."
  (setq-local outline-regexp my-outline-regexp)
  (setq-local outline-level #'my-outline-level))
```

Afterwards it works as you describe it on a buffer with following content if you activate the major mode, e.g., with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-outline-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

```
1keyword_a(first level)
2sub_keyword_aa(second level)
2sub_keyword_ab(second level)
3sub_sub_keyword_aba(third level)

1keyword_b(first level)
2sub_keyword_ba(second level)
3sub_sub_keyword_baa(third level)
```

If you really want to keep `my-outline-mode` you can copy the elisp code into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: Waou! Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. It works. Just need now a liitle bit of time to understand everything. Thanks Drew and Tobias.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to use `1` instead of `*`, `2` instead of `**`, and so on?  If so, have a look at variable `outline-regexp`.  `C-h v` tells you:

> Regular expression to match the beginning of a heading.
>   Any line whose beginning matches this regexp is considered to start a heading.
>   Note that Outline mode only checks this regexp at the start of a line,
>   so the regexp need not (and usually does not) start with `^`.
>   The recommended way to set this is with a `Local Variables:` list
>   in the file it applies to.  See also `outline-heading-end-regexp`.

And from the Emacs manual, node [Outline Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Format.html):

> The length of the matching text determines the level of the heading;
>   longer matches make a more deeply nested level.  Thus, for example, if a
>   text formatter has commands `@chapter`, `@section` and `@subsection` to
>   divide the document into chapters and sections, you could make those
>   lines count as heading lines by setting `outline-regexp` to
>   `"@chap\\|@\\(sub\\)*section"`.
>
> Note the trick: the two words `chapter`
>   and `section` are equally long, but by defining the regexp to match only
>   `chap` we ensure that the length of the text matched on a chapter
>   heading is shorter, so that Outline mode will know that sections are
>   contained in chapters.  This works as long as no other command starts
>   with `@chap`.
>
> You can explicitly specify a rule for calculating the level of a
>   heading line by setting the variable `outline-level`.  The value of
>   `outline-level` should be a function that takes no arguments and returns
>   the level of the current heading.  The recommended ways to set this
>   variable are in a major mode command or with a file local variable.